# Meta query date column add [x] days to validate

Tags: meta-query

I'm retrieving event data from ajax load more plugin using hooks. The requirement is I need to validate the days needed to retrieve. That events 10 days after their end date, they will not be shown in result.

```
$args = [
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'post_type'      => array(TribeEvents::POSTTYPE),
    'posts_per_page' => 20,
    'meta_key'       => '_EventStartDate',
    'orderby'        => '_EventStartDate',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'offset'         => $offset,
    'meta_query' => [
        'key'     => '_EventEndDate',
        'value'   => '_EventEndDate INTERVAL 10 DAY', // <-- this part
        'compare' => '>=',
        'type'    => 'DATE'
    ]
];
```

But ofcourse it does not work and doesn't shown anything in my end. The problem is I needed the **_EventEndDate** to add 10 days but the current solution does not work.

Comment: How is the event date stored? As a timestamp or as a date string? If it's a date string, what is the date format? If it's a timestamp, is the timestamp in UTC time, or in the local time configured for the WP installation?

Comment: @jaswrks, It's saved as like this format [2017-11-05 23:59:59] (taken from DB)

Answer (score 2):

On top of my head this should be something like:

```
'meta_query' => [
        'key'     => '_EventEndDate',
        'value'   => [ $start, $end ],
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        'type'    => 'DATETIME'
    ]
```

You would need to calculate boundaries yourself before passing to the query in this case.

See [Custom Field Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) in Codex for full documentation on parameters available for meta queries.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `array` for `value`, so `[ $begin, $end ]`. For `compare` use `BETWEEN` and `type` is `DATETIME`. `$end` would be now I assume, and the `$begin` ten days ago, so

```
$now = new DateTime(); 
$end = $now->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ); 
$begin = $now->modify( '-10 days' )->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );

$args = [
    'meta_query' => [
        'key'     => '_EventEndDate',
        'value'   => [ $begin, $end ],
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        'type'    => 'DATETIME'
    ]
];
```